# MenuItem with animated actionview does not disappear

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-animation, menuitem, actionview

I have a `MenuItem` (set in a fragment, though I tried in activity and got pretty much the same results) which is supposed to spin like a `ProgressBar` until I receive a broadcast.
I animate the Item by settings an `ImageView` as `actionView` and starting an animation on it. the problem is when `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called again (for example after `invalidateOptionsMenu()` or switching to another fragment) the animation is not cleared while all my item are inflated again thus I lose my pointer to the previous `actionView` and cannot even cancel the animation manually with `cancelAction()`.

here's my code:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_playlist_synch, menu);
}

public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
      ImageView syncView = (ImageView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView( menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_sync));
      Animation rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.rotate);
      rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
      if(animate)
           syncView.startAnimation(rotate);
      else
           //here the animation would always be null because a new sync menuitem is created in onCreateOptionsMenu without clearing the last one
           syncView.clearAnimation();
}
```

Comment: It seems strange that the old ImageView is still visible if all the MenuItems are recreated. Did you try calling `menu.clear` ? 
An alternative would be to use the support [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) which gives much better control on when the items are created/destroyed.

Comment: @mbonnin already tried with menu.clear and still the same results. it simply won't clear when its animated if I stop the animation before invalidateoptionsmenu() it clears just fine. I'm using the support Toolbar already

Comment: You can use the support Toolbar without all the `onCreateOptionsMenu/onPrepareOptionsMenu` if you don't call `setSupportActionBar`. Then the toolbar becomes a regular View in your hierarchy. This might or might not be easier to do what you want.

Comment: I finally solved this by using a ProgressBar with customized view instead of animated ImageView . for whatever reason an animation wouldn't get properly managed on toolbar.